# eclipse plugin project do not build anymore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need help to understand why my plugin project do not build anymore.
Sice few days ago I was been working on this project, but today opening the project all files have build errors (all errors are of the type xxxxx cannot be resolved to a type.

I really new to plugin development, and I'm quite sure some refernce got broken, but I can't understand which one. I made some research but I wasn't able to find something usefull.

thanks in advance for your help, here is a screenshot of the current situation

I tried to create a plugin project from scratch but I get the same problems

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, for those who are facing the same problem I had to go in "eclipse preferences> Plug-in Development > Target Platform" , uncheck Running Platform, click ok and check it again. After that all build errors was disappeared.